# In memory HSQLDB not returning the written results

Tags: java, testing, hsqldb, cucumber-java

I'm using HSQLDB to run tests. In the logs I see the results being written and if I query the result within the same method I see it correctly.
In the next test the result is gone, the database seems to be reset, but I am sure the initial set up of the data is only done once (confirmed from the logs).
So what could be happing with the data?

Might be this;

TEMP tables are not written to disk and last only for the lifetime of the Connection object. The contents of each TEMP table is visible only from the Connection that was used to populate it; other concurrent connections to the database will have access to their own copies of the table

Comment: Probably your test framework does a rollback between each test.

Comment: I'm using Cucumber and I cannot find anything like that in the docs..

Comment: https://cucumber.github.io/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/spring/SpringTransactionHooks.html

Comment: yeah, but no mention of that in our code and even when I move the code that does the insert into the same 'when' method it fails to work